# Hover event for iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

I have a page with "main tabs" which behaves as follows;
1. On hover of these, I show "sub tabs"
2. On click of any of the main tabs, it goes to one of the default sub tab pages.

```
$(".mainlink_href").mouseover(function(){...}
```

Now these behaves as expected on desktop browsers. But on the iPad, when user clicks on any of the main tabs, it always does the hover method execution i.e. shows the sub tabs and does not go the sub tabs page (as in the desktop)

Now I agree, that this is as per expected iPad behavior since there is no mouse cursor to track for hover event otherwise...

But is there any way that I can update the code such that "only for the iPad" it does not go through the hover method for the first click and instead does the click event and directly takes the user to the default sub tab page (i.e. similar to point 2 above in desktop browsers)

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: look into sencha touch :) i'd recommend it, and it would blow you away, simple google search...

Comment: well I am aware of Sencha touch...However I am not sure if there is a need to include Sencha touch here...I just need to override the hover behavior on iPad..I mean can't that be done with a simple JS update..

Comment: try and $.browser to detect if its ipad (not sure you could but worth a try) and $.fn.mouseover = function(){...} so you can override it...or you can look at jquery mobile? or jquery touch :)

Comment: Well...I know how to detect the device (desktop/iPad)..thats not a problem..Thing is how do I override the hover behavior for iPad only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just assign both event handlers, and have the ontouchstart handler remove the onmouseover handler.

```
$(".mainlink_href").mouseover(function(){...});
$(".mainlink_href").ontouchstart(function(){this.mouseover=function(){};});
```

Comment: Thx a lot..Only question is while mouseover handler will get removed...But will the click be executed automatically i.e. user is taken to the href target OR will the user have to click 2nd time for the click behavior..

Comment: Check to find out. But I think it shouldn't be a problem. Touchstart is called before anything else, and onclick is only called after the user released there finger from the screen.

Comment: Actually there is no "click" handler separately...It is through the <a href="" > by which the user is taken to the next page on click..

Comment: I just tried this...The hover event is over written...But the href does not go to it's target..